# How do you remove values not in a cluster using a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this made up of 0 and 1s:

```
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

How do I filter out outliers such that I get something like this:

```
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Such that I remove the outliers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can do this with a *cummulative product* over the second axis with [**`pandas.cumprod`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html):

```
>>> df.cumprod(axis=1)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The same result can here be obtained with [**`pandas.cummin`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html):

```
>>> df.cummin(axis=1)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Maybe add `df.expanding(axis=1).min()
`